# Dynamic Routing vs. Static routing in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Before version 4 of React Router, it was said that you'd establish routes ***statically*** as part of the app's initialization process.

```
// routes.js

const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='playerOne' component={Prompt} />
      <Route path='playerTwo/:playerOne' component={Prompt} />
      <Route path='battle' component={ConfirmBattle} />
      <Route path='results' component={Results} />
      <Route onEnter={checkAuth} path='dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

export default routes
```

And when you'd initialize your app, you'd import your routes and render them.

```
// index.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import routes from './config/routes'

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Today in version 4 of React-Router you do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => (
  <h2>Home</h2>
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

I'm not sure I can see the difference or understand the difference. It is also said that now in V4 it is more commensurate with the way React works. Declarative, component based. Can someone explain it with examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With V4 you don't have a central place for the routes, but rather "sprinkle" them in your components, which makes it more flexible. (https://css-tricks.com/react-router-4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is a bunch of distinct pages, you will not notice much difference between react-router v3 and v4. You will have one router that is a switch between many different pages of the application. Where react-router really shines is that you can include the router in arbitrary components. If you have a page `/settings`, maybe you want to show an additional content panel when the router is `/settings/additional-content`.  You can inject the router into your `SettingsPage`, and conditionally render `AdditionalSettingsComponent` if the route matches. In contrast, react-router v3 would require you to have two components: `SettingsPage` and `SettingsPageAdditionalSettings`.

In react-router v3, you had to declare all of your routes in one place, so you miss out on the ability to optionally render parts of your application to the most fine grained level. Again, if you application is a bunch of distinct pages, you will not see this advantage. But if your application contains pages with components that may or may not be rendered depending on the url, then react-router v4 will be very useful.

From the docs:

> The Route component is perhaps the most important component in React Router to understand and learn to use well. Its most basic responsibility is to **render some UI when a location matches the route’s path**.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

If the location of the app is `/` then the UI hierarchy will be something like:

```
<div>
  <Home/>
  <!-- react-empty: 2 -->
</div>
```

And if the location of the app is `/news` then the UI hierarchy will be:

```
<div>
  <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
  <NewsFeed/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In particular the part referencing the need to render another menu within a component if the path matches :)